# can we put scripts in Libre Office Calc cases?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

i wonder if there is a way to make libreoffice Calc do some code depending on if a case has a sertain value, like:

```
 "while 1 do
     if G6 < 14 do
      print("too few!") in case #or in G7 or whatever
     end
  end"
```

so far i have found nothing, nothing to put a script anywhere

Answer (score -1):

Librebel's answer on another post will do that for you: [running a macro on leaving a cell](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/94719/how-to-run-a-macro-on-leaving-a-special-cell-by-return-if-possible/?answer=94731#post-id-94731)

Comment: Why did you vote down this answer? It does exactly what was asked for.